# Converting this filter statement to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this filter statement:

```
s = [['hello', 'there', 'friend', '.'], ['i', 'am', 'max', ',doe', '"']]
t = [filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2, string) for string in s]
```

This produces my desired results, except that I need `t` to be a list of lists instead of a list of filter objects. How can I transform this into a list comprehension?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x right?

Comment: Yes, I am using python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**filter** solution:

```
t = [list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2, string)) for string in s]
```

`filter` objects only exist in Python 3, so you need to convert it to `list` type using built-in `list()` function. E.g:

```
>>> t = [list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2, string)) for string in s]
>>> t
[['hello', 'there', 'friend'], ['max', ',doe']]
>>>
```

**List comprehension** solution:

```
>>> t = [[x for x in string if len(x) > 2] for string in s]
>>> t
[['hello', 'there', 'friend'], ['max', ',doe']]
>>>
```

Comment: Yea sure, but I would like to forgo the filter and only use list comprehension. This should be possible, correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `filter()`, you can try the following:

```
m = [[e for e in l if len(e) > 2] for l in s]
print m
```

**Output:**

```
[['hello', 'there', 'friend'], ['max', ',doe']]
```

**Edit:**

Remember that the code above is equivalent to:

```
result = []

for l in s:
    sub_result = []
    for e in l:
        if len(e) > 2:
            sub_result.append(e)
    result.append(sub_result)

print result
```